# Node id from tid

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy

How to get the nid from tid, so I can used `node_load` function then used `Field_get_items` to fetch particular fields. I used `taxonomy_select_node()` first but it gives me nids of all nodes related to that tid but I want nids of a particular bundle(content type) so I can display contents only for that content type. Now I am using `Entityfieldquery`, here is my code:
     `if(isset($_GET['tid'])){
     $id=($_GET['tid']);
     $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
     $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
     $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'escorts_product');
     $query->propertyCondition('status', 1);
     $query->fieldCondition('field_description', NULL, $id, '=');
     $result = $query->execute();
     print "<pre>";print_r($result);`
Here I want to get my `field_description` from my content type `escorts_product` for a specific `$id=tid` but it gives array structure for all tids rather than for a specific one I mentioned in argument?

Answer (score 0):

`$query->fieldCondition('field_description', NULL, $id, '=');`
 line should be replaced like this and it will work,
 `$query->fieldCondition('field_your_term_reference_field', tid, $id, '=');`
 then you can get the nid easily.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$termid = array(1); //Where you save term ID(s)
$nids = taxonomy_select_nodes($termid);
$products = array(); //Lets say nodes type is PRODUCT
if (!empty($nids)) {
    foreach ($nids as $nid => $value) {
        echo $products[$value] = node_load($value)->title; // Echo all the titles of related nodes of current term.
    }
}
```